# map function insert same data multiple times (React-Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, accordion

I am trying to implement the React Accordion project using React-Redux.

Here is my **Reducer** code where I have a map function to perform operations one by one on every id:

```js
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    active: [
        { id: 1, status: false },
        { id: 2, status: false },
        { id: 3, status: false },
        { id: 4, status: false }
    ]
}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ACTIVE_STATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                active: state.active.map((acdnobj) => {
                    const panel = document.querySelector(`.panel-${acdnobj.id}`);
                    return {
                        ...acdnobj,
                        acdnobj: acdnobj.id === parseInt(action.id) ? (
                            acdnobj.status = true,
                            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px"
                        ) : (
                            acdnobj.status = false,
                            panel.style.maxHeight = '0px'
                        )
                    }
                }) 
            }
        default:
    }
    return state; 
}
export default reducer;
```

And this is my Accordion where I have another map function to increase the id numbers:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionTypes from '../store/actions/actions';

class Accordion extends Component {
    localDispatch = (key) => {
        this.props.expandAccordion(key.target.value);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.accordions.map((accordion, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <button value={ index + 1 } className={`accordion ${accordion.status}`}
                            onClick={this.localDispatch.bind(this)}>
                                {this.props.title}
                            </button>
                            <div className={`panel panel-${accordion.id}`}>
                                {this.props.content}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        accordions: state.data.active
    };
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        expandAccordion: (key) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.ACTIVE_STATE, id: key})
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Accordion);
```

And in App.js component where I have another map function to fetch data from an excel file:

```js
if(list.length > 0) {
      accordionDIV = list[0].map((d, index) => (
        <Accordion _key={index}
          title = {
            <Table>
              <tr key={d.ID}>
                <td>{d.ID}</td>
                <td>{d.Mail}</td>
                <td>{d.Name}</td>
                <td>{d.PhoneNo}</td>
                <td>{d.City}</td>
                <td>{d.Date}</td>
                <td>{d.Time}</td>
              </tr>
            </Table>
          }
          content = {
            <div>
              <p className="header">
                <span style={{color:"#3c67a5"}}>Shipping Address:</span>
                292 Naqashband Colony, Near rabbania Mosque, Multan
              </p>
              <Table size="sm" className="content">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th style={{width:"10%"}}></th>
                    <th style={{width:"15%"}}>Article No</th>
                    <th style={{textAlign:"left", width:"30%"}}>Product Name</th>
                    <th style={{width:"15%"}}>Quantity</th>
                    <th style={{width:"15%"}}>Price</th>
                    <th style={{width:"20%"}}>Total Amount</th>
                  </tr>  
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {list[1].map((c) => 
                    c.ID === d.ID ? (
                      <tr key={c.ID}>
                        <td> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} size="xs" className="icon" /> </td>
                        <td>{c.ArticleNo}</td>
                        <td style={{textAlign:"left"}}>{c.ProductName}</td>
                        <td>{c.Quantity}</td>
                        <td>{c.Price}</td>
                        <td>{c.TotalAmount}</td>
                      </tr>
                    ) : null
                  )}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
          </div>
          }
        />
      ))
    }
```

The problem is that in the run time I have multiple accordions for the same data.

> Suggest me what can I do for now to solve this problem.

Comment: Can u please share the resultant active state you are getting? Thanks

Comment: If I click the accordion 1 the active state index is "0" and also the same when accordion 2 is clicked the active state is "1" and so on.

Comment: Did you know you are doing state mutations in your reducer, and also that the direct DOM manipulations are a side-effect (*in what should be an otherwise pure function*) and a pretty significant react anti-pattern?

Comment: I also think that manipulating the DOM element in reducer is not a suitable method.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue into a *running* codesandbox that can be live debugged? And more clearly explain the problem? It is a bit difficult to understand what you mean by "The problem is that in the run time I have multiple accordions for the same data."

Comment: No, I have different accordion data and display two times the same accordion data

Comment: What if you first fix the state mutation and side-effect issues in your reducer so you at least have the certainty your state logic is correct? Try moving the open/close logic to the UI being mapped, for example, by adding a "panel-open" class to each panel based on the value of `state.active[index].id === index - 1`. All of your UI should be derived from state, but that is difficult when your state updates have side-issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    active: [
        { id: 1, status: false },
        { id: 2, status: false },
        { id: 3, status: false },
        { id: 4, status: false }
    ]
}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ACTIVE_STATE:
            let newActive = [...state.active];
            newActive = newActive.map((acdnobj) => {
                  const panel = document.querySelector(`.panel-${acdnobj.id}`);
                  panel.style.maxHeight = (acdnobj.id === parseInt(action.id)) ? panel.scrollHeight + "px" : '0px';
                  return {
                      ...acdnobj,
                      status: acdnobj.id === parseInt(action.id)
                  }
            }) 
            
            return {
                ...state,
                active: newActive
            }
        default:
    }
    return state; 
}
export default reducer;
```

This could be the array mutable issue on Javascript so you can use the above code or try with [immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/)

Comment: I tried your this still returns multiple accordions and don't open

Comment: Reducer working perfectly. I think the problem is in the map function, I've used many times. And don't know what to solve this

Comment: @MuzamilHussain Could you let me know the results of redux values(I mean multiple values), please?

Comment: > 4[ {...}, {...}, {...}, {...} ],  4[ {...}, {...}, {...}, {...} ] and so on same values.